# tkinter progressbar: Can I adjust the the thickness of the color segment relative to the size of the progress bar widget containing it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter progressbar widget which functions fine over the course of completing a sequence of N=1000 calculations. I know how to adjust the size of the widget within my main window but not the vertical thickness of the expanding segment (shown in blue below), which is contained within the widget.

[image]

My main window is labelled root, and I currently have

```
N=1000
progress_var = DoubleVar() 
progressbar = Progressbar(master=root,variable=progress_var, length=N,maximum=1) 

progressbar.pack(side=TOP,ipady=20,fill=BOTH, expand=True)
progress_var.set(0)
progressbar.update()


for i in range(N):
    # do stuff
    progress_var.set((i+1)/N)
    progressbar.update()
```

My understanding is that the option ipad=20 controls the vertical dimension of the progressbar widget within root, but that doesn't help me here. Is there an option I can add somewhere?

I'm using Python 3.9 on a Mac with Big Sur.

Comment: Try changing the `.pack(side=TOP,ipady=20,fill=BOTH, expand=True)` to `.pack(side="top", fill="x", ipady=20)`. The `expand=True` sometimes can force the widget to expand in unwanted directions like what you see.

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue for me. I forgot to mention that above the progressbar is a canvas that displays an image:

    background=PhotoImage('background.png')
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10,6]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    background = plt.imread('background.png')
    ax.imshow(background)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

I don't think this should really matter, but maybe it does?